# FFMPEG video conversion time is too long

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I have a website similar to that of youtube. Users can upload their videos in different formats (mov, flv etc). My site will convert these videos to different formats, so that other users can download and rate these videos. I build my site using codeigniter, i am using ffmpeg to convert videos to various formats. One of my issue is that, video conversions are taking so much time.

For example an 76MB video is taking  almost 2 hours to convert to various formats. Is there any solution for my problem.

Comment: Outsource the processing to http://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/ or http://zencoder.com/ or something similar, or get beefier servers.

Comment: Apart from getting a faster server or finding a faster tool, I doubt whether there's anything we can recommend.... (edit: elastic transcoder sounds like a good tip. Is there anything Amazon *doesn't* do?)

Comment: I've used zencoder with good results. But aside from that, you can reduce the quality settings, reduced the number of formats offered, or get more CPU power.

Comment: you can minimise the impact too by instead of converting on the fly immediately scheduling the convertions in a pending table and then do them one after another in order, show users a "conversion in progress" image etc while it converts. Exactly the same way you tube does.  YT also does a very quick 240 compression first to get the basic video up then does the higher quality streams later over time.

Comment: Actually seeing your ffmpeg commands would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

I have good experience working with [transload.it](https://transloadit.com/). It has a very good API and you can upload your files to a S3 bucket and the system can put the video converted in the same bucket.

Take a look at the documentation: https://transloadit.com/docs

Comment: A good thing about Transloadit is it will scale up machines in parallel and encode on those machines in parallel, so no matter how many formats you want to encode too, the time it takes won't linearly scale up up with that, and instead stays pretty around the time it would take to do a single encode on a beefy machine. (disclosure: i work for transloadit!)